# how to get partial string seperated by commas?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a string:

```
string mystring="part1, part2, part3, part4, part5";
```

How can I just return the first 3 elements without splitting them up first?
so like this:

```
string newstring="part1, part2, part3";
```

Comment: How structured is this data? Do you know whether there will be things like commas as part of the data? quotes? line breaks, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find Index of 3rd Comma, and then get the substring.

Example

```
void Main()
{
    string mystring="part1, part2, part3, part4, part5";

    int thirdCommaIndex =  IndexOf(mystring, ',', 3);
    var substring = mystring.Substring(0,thirdCommaIndex-1);
    Console.WriteLine(substring);
}

int IndexOf(string s, char c, int n)
{
  int index = 0;
  int count = 0;
  foreach(char ch in s)
  {
     index++;
    if (ch == c)
     count++;

    if (count == n )
     break;
  }
  if (count == 0) index = -1; 
  return index;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the first three using:

RegEx r = new RegEx(@"(\S+, \S+, \S+), \S+");

I'm sure there is a better way to write the regex, but I think that would do it for basic inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This will parse the string trying to find the third comma and throwing it and everything after it away.

```
        string mystring = "part1, part2, part3, part4, part5";
        UInt16 CommasFound = 0;
        UInt16 Location = 0;
        for (Location = 0; (CommasFound < 3) && 
                           (Location < mystring.Count()); Location++)
               if (mystring[Location].Equals(',')) 
                        CommasFound++;
        if (CommasFound == 3) 
        {
           string newstring = mystring.Substring(0, Location-1);  
        }
        else { // Handle the case where there isn't a third item 
             }
```